# Get actual state of the smartthing's smart device programatically from web service smartApp

Tags: smart-device, smartthings

I am developing a web application which shows the **status** of the all available smart devices in my hub. and I can also control the devices from this application.

For example, if I want to turn on the switch I send "*on*" commands with appropriate contexts to **smartthings** API.

In order the send commands, the devices should be active (it should respond to commands).
And I got the state of the device through API call (*device.status*) but this state found with the device object is not accurate.

For example, the Econet valve is actually responding to my commands.but it states shows **INACTIVE**.
So I can't trust on the values get from "device.status" parameter. is there any other approach?

**Update**: In order to know the current value of devices and take actions according to the current value, we need to know whether the device is responding or not. Currently, we cannot rely on the device status like **ACTIVE, ONLINE** because even after disconnecting the devices from networks the states doesn't change.